# what is entire Template string to allocate Open Nebula VM using XMLRPC method one.vm.allocate

Tags: php, cloud, virtual-machine, xml-rpc, opennebula

I am trying to allocate a `VM` using `Open Nebula XML-RPC Method one.vm.allocate`.

Here I am using `PHP XML-RPC` it is allocating `VM`  but it is not assigned 
 `Os` and Network to the `VM`, actually, I don't how the entire template will look like

### `syntax`

`$result = VirtualMachineManagement::allocate($session_string,$template,$create_On_Hold);
var_dump($result);`

### `code`

`$result = VirtualMachineManagement::allocate('CONTEXT="NETWORK="YES" CPU="1" DISK="IMAGE="CentOS 7.1" IMAGE_UNAME="Servert"" GRAPHICS="LISTEN="0.0.0.0" RANDOM_PASSWD="YES" TYPE="VNC"" HYPERVISOR="kvm" LABELS="ELP02" MEMORY="1024" NIC="NETWORK="Public Network (02)" NETWORK_UNAME="oneadmin"" OS="ARCH="x86_64"" SCHED_DS_REQUIREMENTS="NAME=sata_store" SCHED_REQUIREMENTS ="ID="1" ID="2"" VCPU="1"',true);
var_dump($result);`

Can anyone help me!!

Comment: Can you describe in more details what problems you are facing or paste the errors which you encounter?

Comment: HI thanks @JINESHSHAH I have updated the question can you please let me whether you can help me out